# iOS DispatchQueue and Unable to Update UI

Tags: swift, user-interface, grand-central-dispatch

I'm having trouble updating the UI from the main thread in my app.

I have the following code. As a brief description, I want the for loop to iterate once every A seconds, but I want the nested asynchronous block to begin B seconds after each iteration begins.

```
public func startRecording()
{
    let recordingPeriod = TimeInterval(Float(Constants.windowSize)/Float(Constants.sampleFrequency))
    DispatchQueue.global().async // (1)
    {
        repeat
        {
            for (index, audioRecorder) in self.AudioRecorders.enumerated()
            {
                guard let audioRecorder = audioRecorder else { continue }
                audioRecorder.deleteRecording()
                audioRecorder.record()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + recordingPeriod) // (2)
                {
                    if let pitch = self.finishSampling(audioRecorder: audioRecorder, index: self.AudioRecorders.index(of: audioRecorder))
                    {
                        print(pitch)
                        self.meterViewController?.updateMeter(string: String(pitch)) // (3)
                    }
                }
                // Use usleep here to pause thread which runs overall repeat loop
                // Sets functional time interval for one loop iteration
                usleep(useconds_t((Float(Constants.windowSize)/Float(Constants.samplesPerWindow))/Float(Constants.sampleFrequency)*1000000))
            }
        }
        while self.keepRecording ?? false
    }
}
```

Where (3) simply updates a UILabel:

```
func updateMeter(string: String)
{
    if Thread.isMainThread {
        meterLabel.text = string
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            meterLabel.text = string
        }
    }
}
```

It appears that the `if Thread.isMainThread` statement always returns true, as expected. However, the actual UILabel only appears to get updated for some values of `recordingPeriod`. After changing the value of `recordingPeriod`, the UILabel either updates as intended, or never changes. This seems to me like behaviour that would happen when updating UI on a background thread.

`recordingPeriod` is always sufficiently long enough that the UILabel should have time to update; it is updated no more than a few times per second.

As an aside, if I change (1) and (2) to both call `DispatchQueue.main.` rather than (1) being `DispatchQueue.global()`, the code inside block (2) appears to never run. Shouldn't all the blocks be put on the main queue and be executed at some point?

Comment: Addressing the last bit of your question: if everything is happening on `main` then your repeat/sleep sequence won't give up time on the queue for anything else to run.  If you pause Xcode while running, you should be able to examine queues to see what code blocks are scheduled but not executing.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the actual UILabel only appears to get updated for some values of recordingPeriod ...

This sounds like a situation of timer coalescing, a power saving feature. Consider this example:

```
let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
for i in 0 ..< 1_000 {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i) / 10) {
        let elapsed = CACurrentMediaTime() - start
        print(String(format: "%0.2f", elapsed))
    }
}
```

The first few iterations look fine, but after that you’ll see that GCD will start coalescing them together.

There are ways to stop this coalescing by using `DispatchSourceTimer`, but I might suggest abandoning this timer based triggering of the UI update. E.g. assuming you’re using `AVAudioRecorder`, can you just specify the duration (e.g. `record(forDuration:)`) and then update the UI in the `delegate` methods for your recorder.